# Validating Data in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables from which I am looking to validate data against one another. In one table, I have values that (as of the night before) are considered to be the most "up-to-date". In another table, there are potential changes in that value that are updated later on.

The structure of the data is as follows:

```
TYPE / Date_of_Delivery / Deliverable (integer) / Update_Time
```

An example would be:

```
ABC / 10-30-16 / 4.5 / 9-01-16
```

I would like to end up with a table that is populated showing the "aggregate" changes on any Date_of_Delivery.

For instance, if the date of delivery was changed from 10-30-16 to 10-27-16, I would like it to show something like:

```
ABC / 10-30-16 / -4.5 / 9-01-16
ABC / 10-27-16 / +4.5 / 9-11-16
```

Additionally, if there is a change in the deliverable value:

```
ABC / 10-30-16 / -4.5 / 9-01-16
ABC / 10-27-16 / +6.3 / 9-11-16
```

I have tried using some joins between the tables but I end up matching the same deliverable values against many delivery dates that they shouldn't match against. Any ideas here? Thanks for you help!

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please add back the tag for the database you are really using.

Comment: select * from table1 minus select * from table2 should work.

Answer (score 0):

Below query should help you:

```
select * from table1
minus
select * from table2
```

Above query would give you all the rows of table1 which are different in table2.

Comment: Note that `MINUS` is Oracle specific. With (standard) SQL this should be `EXCEPT`